# Alias for Python command on powershell giving the error : "Can't find a default Python."

Tags: powershell, alias

I created a new alias on my PowerShell for the Python command with the line:

```
New-Alias py Python
```

My alias worked perfectly but when i tried to use it in an other powershell instance it don't works and i got the error :

> Can't find a default Python.

Is an Alias only created for a specific powershell instance ? if yes how can i set this alias permanent and available for all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set the Alias in your profile to have it persist across Powershell sessions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6